# Php short if fails

Tags: php

I have a little problem with "short if" in Php.

```
isset($this->sets[$this->value])?$this->sets[$this->value]:$this->value
```

this drops notices. It looks the `$this->sets[$this->value]` runs even when it doesnt exists. If I do:

```
if (!isset($this->sets[$this->value]))
{
    $this->sets[$this->value] = '';
}
```

it does solve the problem, but then I dont understand something....

EDIT: I refactored:

```
if (isset($this->sets[$this->value]))
{
    $value = $this->sets[$this->value];
}
else
{
    $value = $this->value;
}
return $value;
```

and it works, dunno why....

Comment: Is it a typo that the short version doesn't have the `!`, also in which context is it? And can you provide the notices?

Comment: @kingkero It does the opposite thing.

Comment: It's called the conditional operator, for the record.

Comment: @John What notice are you getting exactly?

Comment: put everything before the question mark in brackets and put the ! back

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: in xxx.php on line yyy

Comment: return 'somethin'.isset($this->sets[$this->value])?$this->sets[$this->value]:$this->value;

Comment: Just "Undefined index:"? No index name is given?

Comment: Can you demonstrate this with a testcase? http://sscce.org [The conditional operator isn't supposed to do this](http://codepad.org/LSa1Cwvl), so you may be making some error we can't see.

Comment: @deceze: If `this->value` is the empty string then that makes sense

Comment: @Lightness Sure. Just making sure he's not truncating the message here.

Comment: @decezee, yes, but it still should detect that it doesnt exist (I think)

Comment: Yes, so it should: http://3v4l.org/4KBWr Are you sure the error is on that line?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit: sadly it can be an empty string, why should it make difference?

Comment: `Undefined index: ` with blank? this smells like $this->value is empty. Checking with `!empty()` which also check for isset?

Comment: @JohnSmith: It doesn't make a difference. I'm just explaining the precise contents of your error message.

Comment: @vlzvl: You pretty much _never_ want `empty`; it does surprising things. For example, check out `empty("0")`!

Comment: @Lightness `empty("0")` is of no surprise whatsoever to me, FWIW. Does `!"0"` surprise you?

Comment: @Lightness Races in Orbit, i forgot the dread zero :). I once encountered a faulty `isset` also by checking an array as 2D while it was just a string. i think PHP handled the second dimension by string or something like that :). I was forced to add `is_array` also except for `isset()`.

Comment: @vlzvl You are all aware that `empty($var)` is just `!isset($var) || $var == false`? Learning what is considered `false` in PHP should be one of the first things you do...

Comment: @deceze: It's surprising that a non-empty string yields `empty()` true, yes. It's surprising if your use of `empty` is designed to detect whether the value exists, not what the value is, as is the case here. `empty` has its uses but I find that, _in general_, its semantics are surprising in most places that I see it used. This is usually because the person who used it didn't read the documentation.

Comment: @Lightness So... don't use functions unless you know what exactly they do...? :o)

Comment: @deceze: Well, of course. But that's entirely orthogonal to whether it's a well-designed part of the language; POLS immediately comes to mind.

Comment: @Lightness If anything, you may debate whether loosely comparing to `false` should work the way it works. I have no problem with `empty` being a *loose comparison to `false` without throwing notices on non-existent variables*, it's a useful operation to have. People projecting their own ideas onto what `empty` is or should do is the real problem. I think this discussion is moving rather OT though. :)

Comment: @deceze: Yes, I would make the same argument for PHP's default-loose comparisons. I don't think it's just "my own idea" that a string that has characters in it should be considered non-empty, though. This definition of "an empty string" is fairly widespread. If nothing else, then, I'd suggest that the name of `empty()` is unfortunate.

Comment: @Lightness Strictly speaking, absolutely. However, this comes from the fact that PHP is "optimised" (quote unquote) for web programming, and HTTP only has strings as a type, and since `0` is `false` so is `"0"`... Yes, it's debatable, but IMO all languages have their quirks in these kinds of operations. It just forces you to write more or less specific comparisons depending on the circumstances. In something like Ruby you'd have to write a lot more *"is set and is not null and is not 0 as a string"* instead (hypothetical example). /OT/OT/OT :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> return 'something'.isset($this->sets[$this->value])?$this->sets[$this->value]:$this->val‌​ue;
> ```

`'something'.isset($this->sets[$this->value])` always evaluates to `true`. You'll need to group the ternary operator expression:

```
return 'something' . (isset($this->sets[$this->value]) ? $this->sets[$this->value] : $this->val‌​ue);
```

*And that's why you always post a complete example in your question, not just a subset!*

Comment: I see, that seems to solved that

Comment: "Post a testcase" 101

Answer (score 1):

It is not true that both operands are evaluated. Try this to see:

```
 true?print('1'):print('2');
```

Only the '1' prints.

The issue is that your first line of code does not do anything in and of itself. You don't assign the result of the expression to anything, you don't use it anywhere, I would not be suprised if zend just discards it.

In your second example, you explicitly create an array element if it does not already exist. If you wanted to do the same thing with the ternary operator, you could do

```
 isset($this->sets[$this->value])?null:($this->sets[$this->value]='');
```

I do not know why you would want to, but it would achieve the same thing as you did in your second example.

Your refactored example can be accomplished using the ternary operator as:

```
return isset($this->sets[$this->value])?$this->sets[$this->value]:$this->value;
```

This is a typical usage of the ternary operator